# CentOS 7 - Okay to use yum and dnf together?

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm, dnf

Another few colleagues and I are responsible for managing a CentOS 7 server. However a few of us prefer dnf as the package manager, while the rest prefer yum, mostly due to being more familiar with it. Since both are based on rpm, I'm really not sure if it's okay to use them together. Neither is there any documentation explicitly advising against using them together (that I can find).

---

Okay, I know this situation of mixing two package managers isn't great, obviously. Ideally I should be encouraging my colleagues to transition to dnf, but that takes time, and people are going to be people.

All I want to know, is whether there's any glaring issues that could potentially be catastrophic. Sources would be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Some differences from a Red Hat slideset.  History is not shared between YUMv3 (`yum`) and YUMv4 (`dnf`).  Databases are in different locations.  A transaction performed using `dnf` cannot be rolled back using `yum` and vice versa. See https://people.redhat.com/mskinner/rhug/q3.2018/MSP-RHUG-YUM-is-dead-Long-live-YUM.pdf

Comment: @fpmurphy That link was very useful. I would accept it if you put it down as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any real problem arising from that. Both build on the `rpm` database and ecosystem, so they can't really break something.

Each one keeps its own cache, so that might use a little more disk space, but that shouldn't be a problem. They might solve some dependencies a little differently, but even if differences arise, I expect those differences to be real edge cases. And even though they might install a different dependency version, that still shouldn't cause trouble for the other package manager.

The only real differences are in [the CLI](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli_vs_yum.html#id4). Here are two differences in behavior which marked me most (note again, this behavior won't break anything for the other package manager):

- `dnf` is notably better at solving dependencies (using the libsolv library from `zypper`).
- `dnf` [will favor installation of packages obsoleting another installed on your system](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli_vs_yum.html#promoting-package-to-install-to-a-package-that-obsoletes-it), where `yum` didn't propose that immediately as an available update.

Comment: Thanks, although this source is probably more useful in helping my colleagues transition rather than showing concretely whether `dnf` and `yum` are compatible... Useful nonetheless

Comment: in short, afaik they are completely compatible.